# Cakephp Update a single field in a record

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I want to update a single record using cakephp. On the controller I have created an entity like this:

```
$User = $this->Users->get($id)
```

then i set that entity to the view for update. In the view i have only one input field i. e. edit your username. but after saving it the model's validator makes all errors of every field like first name is required and all. how to tell the validator that not to verify others during editing a single field in a record.

Comment: Could you please specify in details? what errors you get...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, will not check for any validation

```
$User = $this->Users->get($id) 

if($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])){
    $User = $this->Users->patchEntity($User, $this->request->data);
    if($this->Users->updateAll(['username' => $User->username], ['id' => $User->id])){
       $this->Flash->success(__('The username has been changed));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this resolve your problem? if that so, you can mark the answer correct.